# Swift 4 and Core Data, how do I sort fetch request?

Tags: swift, core-data, swift4

I have a game with 500 records in core data. Each record has an id. They are all unique from 1 to 500.

In Swift 4 or 5, how do I sort the results of this fetch request? I need to sort ascending by prize.id. Thanks in advance.

```
func checkPrizes() {
        
        trace("checkPrizes")
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Prize> = Prize.fetchRequest()
        //finding specific record

        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        outputText.text = ""
        do {
            prizes = try context.fetch(request)
//                try context.save()

                for item in prizes {
                    print("Prize amount: \(item.amount!)")
                    outputText.text = item.amount!
                    print("Prize id: \(item.id!)")
                    outputText.text = item.id!

                    print("Prize region: \(item.region)")
                    outputText.text = String(item.region)

                    print("Prize won: \(item.won)")
//                    outputText.text.append(String(item.won) + "\n")
                }
            print("CheckPrizes count: \(prizes.count)")
            outputText.text = "CheckPrizes count: \(String(prizes.count))"
            } catch {
                print("Failed to retrieve record")
                print(error)
            }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please check Apple documentation first https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506262-sortdescriptors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got your `NSFetchRequest`, you can use sort `var sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?` , which is the sort descriptor of your fetch request.

```
request = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]
```

Or you can just sort the array after your FetchRequest is completed.

Answer (score 0):

```
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
```

Comment: Hey would be great if you also provide some explanation instead of just throwing a piece of code ;)

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is also useful for other users with similar issues.